# React: Button with type="submit" not submitting form, even with valid submit handler and syntax

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, forms

This is not a duplicate of existing questions, because mine has valid syntax, correctly uses `type="submit"` on the `button`, and has a very simple `onSubmit` handler on the `form`. However, clicking the button does not trigger the `onSubmit` handler.

I have reduced the problem down to a very minimal example:

```
<form onSubmit={() => alert("Test")}>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

The problem is that I cannot reproduce this in other parts of the app. The form is nested inside `div`s with no special keyboard or mouse event handling.

Full raw HTML:

```
<div class="Overlay_overlay__6YttW Overlay_visible__7+UKo" tabindex="0">
    <div class="OverlayContext_centerArbitraryChild__nYL5U">
        <button class="OverlayContext_cancelButton__De8Zn" type="button" aria-label="Press escape to cancel" tabindex="1">
            Cancel
        </button>
        <div class="OverlayContext_childContainer__ZKKm0" tabindex="2">
            <div class="FormAttachments_formSubmitterContainer__TQC1I">
                <div>
                    <h1 class="form-title">grssrdgsrg</h1>
                    <p class="form-description">srgsrgsrg</p>
                    <div class="FormRenderer_outer__EFWHr">
                        <form>
                            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What could possibly cause this behavior?

Additional context: If I hook into `onClick` on the button, the event is triggered, but I don't want to do that because I would lose the ability to submit the form by pressing Enter.

Comment: [The code you supplied works](https://jsfiddle.net/kf3zrh8s/).

Comment: There is no `onSubmit` in the second code snippet

Comment: @Konrad I didn't think event handlers would show in the compiled HTML due to how React handles events.

Comment: @Andy Yes, I noted that I cannot reproduce the problem in different contexts. I'm trying to understand which circumstances could possibly lead this minimal form to not work, because it most definitely does *not* work for me.

Comment: I'm not sure how we can help. We can't possibly account for contexts in which this would _not_ work. @Audiopolis. Maybe the issue is the form submitting. Perhaps remove the `onSubmit` listener from the form, change the button type to `type="button"`, and add a click handler to the button instead.

Comment: @Andy I'm not sure either, but still hoping someone more knowledgeable than me will have experienced this before and can name some ways to break the form submit functionality. I noted in an edit that I don't want to use `type="button"` because it breaks the ability to press Enter to submit. Thank you for the suggestion, though. I should also add that the parent of the `Overlay` div (top level) is the `App`. Many siblings, but no parent that should interfere, unless it's somehow possible to break this using a React context.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. The top level `div` ("overlay" shown in the compiled HTML) had an `onClick` handler that called `e.preventDefault()`. I did not expect that to suppress the form submission, especially when pressing Enter and not even clicking the submit button, but I guess it must go like this:

Enter pressed -> Submit button click simulated -> Event propagates -> Default prevented -> Form is not submitted.

Removing that line makes it work. (Unfortunately, it breaks other functionality, but that's a different problem.)